# javascript library for state workflow presentation

Tags: javascript, flowchart

I would like to know of a good javascript library for workflows, I'm currently using [Joint JS](http://www.jointjs.com/), but I need something more visual impressive (users only like that).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558972/javascript-flowchart-library-for-workflow-visualization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this astonishing library, called [WireIt](http://neyric.github.com/wireit/index.html).